# Firebase storage bandwith issue?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

[image: Bandwith]

As you can see i just saw my Bandwith to firebase storage and i'm just in test mode with only 3 images.. There is a way to check what happened here ? Or maybe there is a way to download the image locally for futur use ? What the best alternative for avoid too much bandwith ? im using react

Answer (score 0):

There is no auditing of the activity in your Cloud Storage bucket.  The console will just tell you what your usage is, so you can better estimate billing.  If you want to know exactly what happened, you will have to keep your own logs.